# Classes for sentence-like readability

Tags: c++, object-oriented, c++11

If we have a set of `class`es or `struct`s such as:

```
struct Point
{
    float x;
    float y;
};

struct Square
{
    Point topLeft;
    float width;
};

struct Circle
{
    float radius;
    Point middle;
};
```

If we need to add some functionality to to these, does something like below make sense?

```
inline Point middleOf(const Square &square)
{
    float halfWidth(square.width/2.0f);
    return Point{
        square.topLeft.x + halfWidth,
        square.topLeft.y + halfWidth};
}

inline Point middleOf(const Circle &circle)
{
    return circle.middle;
}

class MoveSquare
{
public:
    MoveSquare(Square &squareToMove)
    :
    squareToMove(squareToMove)
    {}

    void to(const Point &target)
    {
        squareToMove.topLeft = offsetHalfWidth(target);
    }

private:    
    Point offsetHalfWidth(Point p)
    {
        const float halfWidth(squareToMove.width / 2.0f);
        return Point{
            p.x - halfWidth,
            p.y - halfWidth};
    }

private:
    Square &squareToMove;
};

class MoveCircle
{
public:
    MoveCircle(Circle &circle)
    :
    circleToMove(circle)
    {}

    void to(Point position)
    {
        circleToMove.middle = position;
    }

private:
    Circle &circleToMove;
};

inline MoveSquare move(Square &square)
{
    return MoveSquare{square};
}

inline MoveCircle move(Circle &circle)
{
    return MoveCircle{circle};
}
```

The main idea is being able to have code that reads like a sentence. Such as:

```
int main() {

    Square aSquare;
    aSquare.topLeft = Point{1,1};
    aSquare.width = 3;

    Circle aCircle;
    aCircle.middle = Point{1,1};
    aCircle.radius = 2;

    move(aSquare).to(Point{1,1});
    move(aSquare).to(middleOf(aCircle));

    move(aCircle).to(middleOf(aSquare));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want your code to read like English, try [tag:Objective-C].  ;)  I'm not sure how well accepted this would be in the C++ community, but we definitely strive for verbose code in ObjC.

Comment: I think this will break OOP, just a little... What if you'll want to inherit Square, with RoundedSquare? And that `move`, should have global visibility, if you want to use it for readability. Otherwise you have to `use namespace` it. I don't think this is a good idea. Do you thought about koenig lookup, for this?

Comment: @tower120 hmm koenig lookup. What would using that look like for this?

Comment: Why not: `aSquare.moveTo(Point{1,1});`  or `aSquare.moveTo(aCircle.center())`

Comment: @LokiAstari for many cases I agree that would be a good solution and reads nice and clearly. The situation I had in mind was one where the types are from a third party library. In that case you can not change them at all.

Comment: There are quite a few cases where you can not just go adding to an interface. It might be third party code and your use case just does not fit in there. You might need to preserve some ABI, or just not want to recompile everything else that uses that class while the interface for the additional functionality evolves.

Comment: Looking back I see the question doesn't explain that. I would edit it but then that would invalidate the answers so far. Maybe a second question is called for...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, a negative remark. The power of C++ means that it is not uncommon for new C++ developers to try and make C++ look like a language they feel more familiar with - sometimes English, sometimes a programming language they already know. This is almost always a bad thing - you need to speak like a native.

However, whilst C++ used for mainstream development does have generally understood idioms, one of its capabilities and original design aims is to try to support different styles of programming.

As well as trying to create an application syntax which is more English like, you are externalizing functionality into proxy objects rather than using the OOP paradigm of member functions. IMHO, this is perfectly legitimate as an experiment.

What you'll likely find is that as you pursue this you gave to make various compromises that finally result in you deciding that maybe this is not he way to go. Or maybe not. See what you find.

If I were to go down this path, I'd probably play with using templates to try and get some generic behaviour, given that the OOP approach us not being used. How exactly this goes will depend on whatever other functionality is needed.

For example:

```
template<class T>
class Move
{
public:
    Move(T& thing)
        : thing_(thing)
    {}
    virtual void to(const Point& position) = 0;
    T& thing() { return thing_; }
private:
    T& thing_;
};

class MoveSquare : public Move<Square>
{
public:
    MoveSquare(Square &squareToMove)
        : Move<Square>(squareToMove)
    {}

    virtual void to(const Point &target)
    {
        thing().topLeft = offsetHalfWidth(target);
    }

private:
    Point offsetHalfWidth(const Point& p) 
    {
        const float halfWidth(thing().width / 2.0f);
        return Point{ p.x - halfWidth, p.y - halfWidth };
    }
};

class MoveCircle : public  Move<Circle>
{
public:
    MoveCircle(Circle &circle)
        : Move<Circle>(circle)
    {}

    virtual void to(const Point& position)
    {
        thing().middle = position;
    }

};
```

Comment: that method shouldn't be virtual

Comment: also, what is the point of the `Move`? It does nothing

Comment: If this is C++11 then it could be good to add  `override` or `final` to communicate more clearly and get more help from the compiler.

Answer (score 5):

It reads like a mandate, and not necessarily a sentence which makes this point trivial.

Notice how all are English:

> Run this code!
>
> The code ran
>
> The code is running

This design doesn't let you define movement inside the object that moves, so you need to look into different places to find out how the object moves.

Your way is also weird and unfamiliar. Consider [how Qt does it](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setPos-2):

> ```
> void QGraphicsItem::setPos(const QPointF & pos)
> ```
>
> Sets the position of the item to `pos`, which is in parent coordinates.
>   For items with no parent, `pos` is in scene coordinates.
>
> The position of the item describes its origin (local coordinate (0,
>   0)) in parent coordinates.

Answer (score 5):

It's an interesting concept, but not exactly how I would expect this to be structured.

First, it's superfluous to have an external function to return the middle of a circle when it's already available though it's property.

I would expect a class method to move the object. Something like `circle.move(x,y)`. If you're concerned with making the size immutable, simply set it in a constructor and disallow external access to the radius property.

Comment: I was thinking more for the cases when you can't add anything directly to the classes. I guess I should have been clearer about that in the question...

Comment: @PeterSW: Just in general, or do you have some examples?  Even if this were a factor, you would have to stick to `struct`s as having `class`es would suggest that the data members should be `private`, thus preventing the use of free functions.

Comment: @Jamai In using free functions you're limited to the public interface... but there's often plenty of scope to build more functionality from that.

Comment: @PeterSW: Right, which is why I asked.  I'm not saying that this is plain wrong, but unexpected for basic use (as you've said, clarification should've been added, but it would also invalidate this answer).

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and call out that I don't know this language. I'm speaking from a completely abstract design point of view. It looks like I may have misunderstood the question.

Comment: @ckuhn203: You are generally correct about the use of member functions over free functions (my wording of course), and you *are* allowed to comment on any part of the code.

Answer (score 3):

There are few problems. I will start with minor, and end with major.

---

### Minor

1. `MoveSquare::to` accepts a parameter by const reference, but `MoveSquare::offsetHalfWidth` accepts the parameter by value. Since `offsetHalfWidth` doesn't modify it's parameter, it should be passed by const reference
2. `MoveSquare::to` just assigns the result of `MoveSquare::offsetHalfWidth` to some variable. Why not merge these two methods?

---

### Major

I am particularly fond of the [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle), therefore I cringed when I saw your code. I would say it is a good example of when NOT to use a proxy pattern.

I would add a method to each of the structures with this signature :

```
void MoveTo(const Point &target);
```

it makes the code simpler, and therefore easier to understand.

Also, instead of having overloaded functions to calculate the middle point, I would add a method to the structure.

They would look like :

```
struct Square
{
    Point topLeft;
    float width;

    void MoveTo(const Point &target);
    Point MiddlePoint() const;
};

struct Circle
{
    float radius;
    Point middle;

    void MoveTo(const Point &target);
    Point MiddlePoint() const;
};
```

This way, all calculations for a specific structure is localized, and easier to find.

Overloaded functions are making the code harder to understand. When number of such structures is high, then number of functions is high as well. Finding the correct one can be challenging.

Comment: Does C++ have inheritance? It looks like both of those could inherit `MoveTo` from a shared parent class.

Comment: @ckuhn203 Yes, but why? Those structures are PODs, and those functions are specific (and different) for each structure.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it looks like the `MoveTo` method in this answer is "copy paste" code. There's nothing different about them.

Comment: @ckuhn203 What are you talking about? What is copy paste code? The bottom code is the suggested signature of the structures. Those methods would still need implementation.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm talking about. Thanks for clarifying that. In that case, they should share an *interface* and override the MoveTo method.

Comment: @ckuhn203: In C++ it is possible to use duck typing interfaces without a common base class (it is called static polymorphism). Introducing inheritance hierarchies with virtual functions is to be avoided until they are truly needed.

Answer (score 2):

Object names in the form of `aSomething` are not only un-useful, but also prevent additional objects.  Otherwise, you'll have `anotherSomething` and `thirdSomething` and so on.

Sure, it *may* still sound better in English, but it just makes your code messier and more restrictive.  Although striving to have the code look more English-like is nice, you can still use looser naming that's still nicely readable by others.

Alternatives to this may depend on your design, as already mentioned by others.  As good naming is already one of the hardest things to do in programming, it may be worth looking at similar designs to see how it's done by others.

Answer (score 2):

> If we need to add some functionality to to these, does something like below make sense?

In some contexts, it probably does (though I can't think of any). It does look (to me) like a case of the "I will write C in any language" syndrome.

I would find this implementation cumbersome and obscure, especially since the equivalent canonical code is much simpler:

```
struct Point
{
    float x;
    float y;
};

struct Figure { virtual void move(const Point& abspos) = 0; }
// TODO: add virtual destructor to Figure

struct Square: Figure
{
    Point topLeft;
    float width;
    void move(const Point& abspos) override { topLeft = abspos; }

    inline Point middle() const
    {
        float halfWidth(width/2.0f);
        return Point{
            square.topLeft.x + halfWidth,
            square.topLeft.y + halfWidth};
    }
};

struct Circle: Figure
{
    float radius;
    Point middle;
    void move(const Point& abspos) override { middle = radius; }
};
```

Here's an updated main:

```
int main() {

    Square aSquare;
    aSquare.topLeft = Point{1,1};
    aSquare.width = 3;

    Circle aCircle;
    aCircle.middle = Point{1,1};
    aCircle.radius = 2;

    // move(aSquare).to(Point{1,1});
    aSquare.move(Point{1,1});

    // move(aSquare).to(middleOf(aCircle));
    aSquare.move(aCircle.middle);

    // move(aCircle).to(middleOf(aSquare));
    aCircle.move(aSquare.middle());

    return 0;
}
```

Note: The algorithm is not equivalent to yours, but it's the interface/client code that looks interesting, not necessarily the implementation of the functions.

Comment: I'm just wondering what you reasons for thinking that the question code suffers from "I will write C in any language" syndrome?

Comment: @PeterSW, The "I can write C in any language syndrome" is a name I use for the attempt to force constructs in a language, to resemble constructs in another language, solely due to the familiarity level of the developer.

Comment: I think I understood what you meant, I'm more wondering why you think this is the case for the original code? I'm pretty sure it's impossible to write such a construct in C.

It it because it doesn't use inheritance?